# Check if strings from list A exist in list B (by regex)

Tags: python, list, search

```
listA = ['Leonardo_da_Vinci', 'Napoleon', 'Cao_Cao', 'Elton_John']
listB = ['123_Leonardo_da_Vinci_abc.csv', '456_Cao_Cao_def.csv']

listC = ['Napoleon', 'Elton_John']
```

I would like to check if the items in `listB` contain the values in `listA`, and returns `listC` (i.e. the list that is missing in `listB`). For this purpose I would like to use regex (and no other heuristics) like (example of checking `Leonardo_da_Vinci`): `.*Leonardo_da_Vinci.*`

The reason for regex is that the example above is just the simplest mockup and the data I use is much bigger. It is also good to have a generalised code which works on another data in future.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use regex? It's overkill for your use case and will make the code more complicated than simple `in` checks with python

Comment: The reason for regex is that the example above is just the simplest mockup and the data I use is much bigger. It is also good to have a generalised code which works on another data in future.

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense. I'd still be careful about using a dynamically generated regex like this. It's just incredible slow compared to alternative solutions. At least if you do have a big amount of data. Otherwise you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import re

def exists_csv_with_name(name:str, source_list: list) -> bool:
    regex = re.compile(fr'.*{name}.*')
    return any(regex.match(source_str) for source_str in source_list)
    
listC = [name for name in listA if not exists_csv_with_name(name, listB)]
```

Comment: If there are alternative ways, you are more than welcome! Thanks in advance

Comment: @user7665853 In what sense alternative ways? What in this solution does not fully satisfy you?

Comment: It was supposed to ask more volunteers to get other nice-to-have solutions. Now, I tested a bit further, and it seems I have a problem with values in UTF-8. Somehow values like `Frédéric_Chopin` was excluded from the outcome. Is there a way to indicate it in your code? (although, I am not entirely sure if the encoding is the exact problem)

Comment: If I understood you right, when you have `listA = ['Frédéric_Chopin']` and 
`listB = ['110_Frédéric_Chopin.csv']`, then `'Frédéric_Chopin'` is not in `listC`. That is exactly the behavior you asked for!

Comment: Sorry, I think this is another problem for UTF-8 encoding in my machine. Something is wrong with matching the filename in UTF-8, and I am just puzzled...I think your code is fine for the original purpose.